# TCP tunnel over SSH in Rust

Tags: http, ssh, tcp, rust, tunnel

I'm trying to write a small program in Rust to accomplish basically what `ssh -L 5000:localhost:8080` does: establish a tunnel between `localhost:5000` on my machine and `localhost:8080` on a remote machine, so that if an HTTP server is running on port 8080 on the remote, I can access it on my local via `localhost:5000`, bypassing the remote's firewall which might be blocking external access to 8080.

I realize `ssh` already does exactly this and reliably, this is a learning project, plus I might be adding some functionality if I get it to work :) This is a barebones (no threading, no error handling) version of what I've come up with so far (should compile on Rust 1.8):

```
extern crate ssh2; // see http://alexcrichton.com/ssh2-rs/

use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::str;
use std::net;

fn main() {
  // establish SSH session with remote host
  println!("Connecting to host...");
  // substitute appropriate value for IPv4
  let tcp = net::TcpStream::connect("<IPv4>:22").unwrap();
  let mut session = ssh2::Session::new().unwrap();
  session.handshake(&tcp).unwrap();
  // substitute appropriate values for username and password
  // session.userauth_password("<username>", "<password>").unwrap();
  assert!(session.authenticated());
  println!("SSH session authenticated.");

  // start listening for TCP connections
  let listener = net::TcpListener::bind("localhost:5000").unwrap();
  println!("Started listening, ready to accept");
  for stream in listener.incoming() {
    println!("===============================================================================");

    // read the incoming request
    let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
    let mut request = vec![0; 8192];
    let read_bytes = stream.read(&mut request).unwrap();
    println!("REQUEST ({} BYTES):\n{}", read_bytes, str::from_utf8(&request).unwrap());

    // send the incoming request over ssh on to the remote localhost and port
    // where an HTTP server is listening
    let mut channel = session.channel_direct_tcpip("localhost", 8080, None).unwrap();
    channel.write(&request).unwrap();

    // read the remote server's response (all of it, for simplicity's sake)
    // and forward it to the local TCP connection's stream
    let mut response = Vec::new();
    let read_bytes = channel.read_to_end(&mut response).unwrap();
    stream.write(&response).unwrap();
    println!("SENT {} BYTES AS RESPONSE", read_bytes);
  };
}
```

As it turns out, this kind of works, but not quite. E.g. if the app running on the remote server is the [Cloud9 IDE Core/SDK](https://github.com/c9/core), the main HTML page gets loaded and some resources as well, but **requests for other resources** (`.js`, `.css`) **systematically come back empty** (whether requested by the main page or directly), i.e. **nothing is read in the call to `channel.read_to_end()`**. Other (simpler?) web apps or static sites seem to work fine. Crucially, when using `ssh -L 5000:localhost:8080`, even Cloud9 Core works fine.

I expect that other more complex apps will also be affected. I see various potential areas where the bug might be lurking in my code:

1. Rust's stream reading/writing APIs: maybe the call to `channel.read_to_end()` works differently than I think and just accidentally does the right thing for some kinds of requests?
2. HTTP: maybe I need to tinker with HTTP headers before forwarding the request to the remote server? or maybe I'm giving up to soon on the response stream by just calling `channel.read_to_end()`?
3. Rust itself -- it's my first relatively earnest attempt at learning a systems programming language

I've already tried playing with some of the above, but I'll appreciate any  suggestions of paths to explore, preferably along with an explanation as to why that might be the problem :)

Comment: Thanks, you're right, better keep focus :)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the code to run locally, but `vec![0; 8192]` is suspicious. This creates a vector with many zeroes. if you read one byte from the socket, there will still be 8191 zeroes following it in the buffer. When you write that back out, you are writing all those zeroes, which the remote side has to deal with. You should only be sending the data you read.

Comment: Additionally, you probably need to read the input until the HTTP headers are complete (`\r\n\r\n`, IIRC), then send that upstream.

Comment: re: `vec![0; 8192]`: That sounds like a trail! I mistakenly thought they just went away (or rather, that `stream.read()` truncated the pre-allocated vector if it turned out to be too long) -- simply because when I log the request to STDOUT, they're gone. But now you mention it, that's probably because the string gets truncated at the first null by the terminal emulator? I'll look into it tonight and report back.

Comment: re: `\r\n\r\n`: Right again, this was just a quick and dirty way to pre-allocate more than enough for a typical HTTP request, since I thought (again, mistakenly) that the extra nulls were getting thrown away. The requests for the resources that turn up blank aren't getting truncated though (according to the log), so it sounds more like a case of the extra nulls messing things up rather than headers missing.

Comment: @Shepmaster So it turns out I was approaching the entire thing too naively :) Getting rid of the nulls in the request got me started, but there's more. Basically, I need to be smarter than waiting for the end of the streams -- when they're keep-alive, they won't close automatically, so I need to partially parse the HTTP headers and detect the end of the response based on that. Would you like to close this with an answer to this general effect? I'd be happy to accept it, I would've gotten nowhere without your help.

Comment: nah. You figured it out, I just gave clues. Go ahead and self-answer. That is what I was (poorly) referring to when saying you should look for the end of the headers though.

Comment: In that case I think I'll wait until I have some fully working code to post. If you change your mind in the meantime though, don't hesitate!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: use Go and its networking libraries for this particular task

Turns out my very rudimentary understanding of how HTTP works may be at fault here (I initially thought I could just shovel data back and forth over the ssh connection, but I haven't been able to achieve that -- if someone knows of a way to do this, I'm still curious!). See some of the suggestions in the comments, but basically it boils down to the intricacies of how HTTP connections are initiated, kept alive and closed. I tried using the [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) crate to abstract away these details, but the ssh2 Session can't be used in hyper handlers due to thread safety restrictions (at least not in 2016 it couldn't).

At this point, I decided there's no *simple*, *high-level* way for a *beginner* to achieve this in Rust (I'd have to do some low-level plumbing first, and since I can't do that reliably and idiomatically, I figured it's not worth doing at all). So I ended up forking this [SSHTunnel](https://github.com/SommerEngineering/SSHTunnel) repository written in Go, where library support for this particular task is readily available, and my solution to the Cloud9 setup described in the OP can be found [here](https://github.com/dlukes/Ground8).

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on, or reference to, the supposed lack of threadsafety of crate ssh2 and its underlying libssh2? According to https://www.libssh2.org/ _Thread-safe_ is listed under _Capabilities and Features_.

Comment: @sampi Honestly a lot could have changed in the five years since :) I think the problem was that I couldn't share `ssh2::Session` between threads. Old docs from back then show the type as not being `Sync`, which would back that up: https://docs.rs/ssh2/0.2.10/ssh2/struct.Session.html. Which made me assume libssh2 is not threadsafe, but this GitHub comment suggests it's more nuanced, as you've noted: https://github.com/alexcrichton/ssh2-rs/issues/29#issuecomment-165190344.

Comment: @sampi I edited the answer to make the claim less sweeping and note the historical context.